# Does React renders Component due to props?

Tags: reactjs

According to that link: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

`render()` may be triggered with `new props`. Could someone give me a code example for that? I cannot see how props change invoke rendering! Please not by changing the props via the state; then it is `setState()` that invokes `render()`...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) - this is it's signature - it returns a boolean. Props is there so you can compare and manually say whether the component should update.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

Answer (score 0):

For function components `React.memo` is the replacement for `shouldComponentUpdate` which is used with class components.

```js
const myComponent = React.memo(props => {
     ... 
     code of React.FunctionComponent
     ...
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.propA === nextProps.propA
);
```

`React.memo` gets two arguments shown above: a React.FunctionComponent which will be wrapped around by `memo` and an optional function that returns a boolean.

When the function returns true, the component will not be re-rendered. If the function is omitted then its default implementation in `React.memo` works like the implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate` in React.PureComponent. E.g. it does shallow comparison of `props`, the difference is that only `props` are taken into account because `state` doesn’t exist for functional components.

Answer (score 0):

Using hooks is neater to show. The new props data passed to ComponentB causes a re-rendering of ComponentB:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ComponentB from '...'

const ComponentA = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)        // data = 0
  handleChangeProp = item => setData(item)  // data = 1 
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick{() => handleChangeProp(1)}
      <ComponentB props={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you do a setState(newState) or when you pass in changed props the component will re render, this is why you can't mutate. The following **will not work** because you set state with mutated state.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [c, setC] = useState({ c: 0 });
  console.log('in render:', c);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setC(state => {
            state.c++;
            console.log('state is:', state);
            return state;
          })
        }
      >
        +
      </button>
      <Child c={c.c} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

That code "won't work" because pressing + will not cause a re render, you mutated state and then set state with the same object reference so React doesn't know you changed anything.

This is how React detects changes, you may think that comparing `{c:0}` to `{c:1}` is a change but because you mutated there actually is no change:

```
const a = {c:1};
a.c++;//you "changed" a but a still is a
```

To indicate a change in React you have to create a new reference:

```
const a = {c:1};
const b = {...a};//b is shallow copy of a
a===b;//this is false, even though both a and b have same internal values
```

This means you can also have **unintended** renders because you create an object prop that may have the same value but still is a different reference than the last time you created it.

Note that even `<Child prop={1}` will cause Child to render if Child is not a pure component (see links at the end).

What you want to avoid is doing `<Child prop={{c:value}}` because every time you pass prop it'll force Child to render and React to do a virtual DOM compare even if `value` didn't change. The virtual DOM compare will probably still detect that Child virtual DOM is the same as last time and won't do an actual DOM update.

The most expensive thing you can do is `<Child onEvent={()=>someAction(value)}`. This is because now the virtual DOM compare will fail even if value and someAction did't change. That's because you create a new function every time.

Usually you want to memoize creating props in a container, [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/react-redux-hooks) is an example of doing this with react-redux hooks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192552/1641941) is an example with stateful components passing handlers.